# Rails CanCanCan - Duvida sobre tabela de Roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relacionamento, authorization

Boa tarde, Eu tenho os seguintes models:

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  VALID_USERNAME_REGEX = /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]*[_|-|.]*[a-zA-Z0-9]*\z/
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A([\w+\-].?)+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :username, presence: true,
        format: {with: VALID_USERNAME_REGEX,
                 message: "Somente letras, numeros e simbolos (. _ -)"}
  validates :email, presence: true,
        format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}

  has_many :projects
  has_many :users_projects
  has_many :roles
  has_many :roles, through: :project
  has_many :shared_projects, through: :users_projects, source: :project
end
```

Project.rb

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role

  has_many :users_projects
  has_many :collaborators, through: :users_projects, source: :user

  has_many :boards

  validates :name, presence: true
  #validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

Role.rb

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects
  has_many :users, through: :projects
end
```

O usuario pode ter 3 roles diferentes, **Product Manager**, **Scrum Master** e **Developer**. O problema é que, o role de um usuário depende do projeto a qual ele está envolvido, sendo que o mesmo usuário pode ser Product Manager em um, e em outro ele pode ser Desenvolvedor por exemplo.
Sendo assim, o role de um usuário está mais ligado a um projeto do que ao próprio usuário. A minha dúvida é, qual a melhor maneira de montar isso? Da maneira como eu fiz, quando eu vou popular meu banco, eu recebo um erro falando que Role é obrigatório.
Alguém poderia me dar uma mão?

Answer (score 0):

Felipe, não sei se entendi direito, mas acho que eu faria algo assim.

```
User

Role

Project
  has_many :project_users
  has_many :users, thought: :project_users

ProjectUser
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
```

Pelo que entendi o usuário pode estar ligado a vários projetos com papéis diferentes.

Ai você pode criar um validador único para o escopo.